# SQLPLUS embedded in linux script does not work as expected

Tags: linux, oracle, sh, sqlplus

I have the following script segment in a Linux script:

```
sqlplus /
<<QUERY_1
                    UPDATE BATCH_FILE SET BATCH_ID = 0 WHERE BATCH_ID  = -1;
                    COMMIT;
                    exit

QUERY_1
```

I am expecting the update to occur and the script to exit sqlplus

What actually happens is the query is not executed, and the script exits leaving sqlplus logged into my database with a SQL> prompt.  I can execute the statements from the prompt, but of course, that is not what I want to do.

My current version of Oracle is 12.2.0.1

Comment: Maybe the slash should be a backslash?

Comment: I have tried the exit with or without the ;  I consider without to most likely be correct as no ; is required when executing from interactive command prompt

Comment: @wildplasser - the forward slash is correct.  It indicates to connect with os authentication.

Comment: Aha, it is the empty form of `scott/tiger`! In that case, add a backward slash too. Otherwise the output of the HERE-document will miss its target. (and the sqlplus will probably end up in interactive mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the HERE-document is intended for the std input of sqlplus, but for the shell **a command should be on a single line**. Adding a backslash will make the shell ignore the line-end, combining the two physical lines into one logical line:

---

```
sqlplus / \
<<QUERY_1
                    UPDATE BATCH_FILE SET BATCH_ID = 0 WHERE BATCH_ID  = -1;
                    COMMIT;
                    exit

QUERY_1
```

---

Or just:

---

```
sqlplus / <<QUERY_1
                    UPDATE BATCH_FILE SET BATCH_ID = 0 WHERE BATCH_ID  = -1;
                    COMMIT;
                    exit

QUERY_1
```